Spring Boot + Flyway + Testcontainers(oracle) fails "CREATE USER" ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
I am running spring boot v2.3.5 application with oracleDb (com.oracle.jdbc.ojdbc8 v12.2.0.1) and following testcontainer dependencies:
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.20.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle-free</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

Here is the testcontainer initialization:
public class TestcontainersInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    static OracleContainer oracleContainer = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-free:23.5-slim-faststart")
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
            .withDatabaseName("test")
            .withPassword("test")
            .withPrivilegedMode(true)
            ;

    
    static {
        Startables.deepStart(oracleContainer).join();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none",
                "spring.datasource.url=" + oracleContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                "spring.datasource.username=" + oracleContainer.getUsername(),
                "spring.datasource.password=" + oracleContainer.getPassword(),
                "spring.flyway.enabled=" + "true",
                "spring.flyway.url=" + oracleContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                "spring.flyway.user=" + oracleContainer.getUsername(),
                "spring.flyway.password=" + oracleContainer.getPassword(),
                "spring.flyway.schemas="
        ).applyTo(ctx.getEnvironment());
    }
}

While the application is running, flyway scripts are running. But flyway fails for following sql content:
CREATE USER dummy_user IDENTIFIED BY dummy_password;

and says: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
I couldn't find any solution to solve this issue. How can i solve this issue

Sounds like your DB user "test" is expected to have DBA privileges, but doesn't?

@AlexPoole, if that is the case, how can i add the correct privileges? (Before running the flyway scripts)
